# How to get Jacobian of vector matrix contain states derivative

Tags: matlab

Here is a **3*1 matrix(A)** contains steady space parameters and their derivative (x1dot = dx1/dt and ...) as :

```
A = [ x1dot-10*x1;10*x2dot-10*x2;x3dot-5*x3];
```

We want to get the jacobian of this matrix related to its states [x1,x2,x3] but what can we do for their derivatives?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the [jacobian](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/jacobian.html) function. In your case:

```
jacobian(A, [x1, x2, x3])
```